# Populating records using BETWEEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, between

A record has its date in 'yyyy.MM.dd' format (for example, 2018.05.02),
and I have made a query to populate certain records between a certain time frame.

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE (BATCHDT '2018.01.01' AND '2018.05.01');
```

The query looks fine, at least to me, but does not work on my MSSQL.
Please help.

Comment: Where's the `BETWEEN`?

Comment: Ah, sry, original sql query looks like this:
    SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE (BATCHDT BETWEEN '2018.01.01' AND '2018.05.01');

Answer (score 1):

Just use ANSI standard formats:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
WHERE BATCHDT BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-05-01';
```

No conversion should be necessary.  I do not recommend using `BETWEEN` with dates, because they might have a time component.  A safer method is:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
WHERE BATCHDT >= '2018-01-01' AND
      BATCHDT < '2018-05-02';
```

Comment: Date format of mine looks like: 2018.01.01 
and no conversion required?

Comment: `cast` works fine if you use  it against the literals or variables

Comment: @JiminChoi . . . SQL Server is pretty good about converting strings.  You should be in the  habit of writing clean code, including using ISO/ANSI standard formats for dates.

Comment: Always use ISO Standard 8601 for representing the date literals. It will avoid confusion. For more information [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html). i.e., YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0):

try this.

In SQL a `Date type` is a `Date type` regardless of the format. Using it will mean `casting the field` against literals

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE cast(BATCHDT as date) BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-05-01'

--- 2018-jan-01  and 2018-May-01
```

Comment: Aren't you using missing the `BETWEEN` keyword too?

Comment: does the cast statement automatically parse the format 2018.01.01 into 2018-01-01 ? Wow

Comment: `cast` will allow SQL to parse based on its standard.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to convert your source field data into acceptable format for date conversion.

If your source data 'yyyy.MM.dd' format (for example, 2018.05.02)

then you can change it into format that acceptable for date conversion, for example 'YYYYMMDD', by remmoving the '.' character (so your date record become 20180502)
the query could be as follows

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE cast(REPLACE(BATCHDT,'.','') as date) BETWEEN '20180101' AND '20180501'
```

by default in MSSQL server also recognize 'YYYYMMDD' format for conversion into date, so you also not required to cast it into date first

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE REPLACE(BATCHDT,'.','') BETWEEN '20180101' AND '20180501'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to keep BATCHDT as DATE datatype to avoid confusion with time values, which will come with DATETIME.

Also, suggest you to use [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) standard for representing dates.

BETWEEN is a inclusive operator. So, below 
`BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-05-01'` will turn to be

```
BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2018-05-01 00:00:00.000'
```

So, it will not return values which fall on date 2018-05-01. So, you have to apply below BETWEEN condition

```
BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2018-05-01 23:59:59.997'
```

Instead of that, I would suggest you to go for DATE operator, which is very straight forward for BATCHDT.

```
BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-05-01'
```